# Margin notes *and* footnotes in a table environment

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable, marginpar

I am working on a translation. The original text has margin notes, and I also need footnotes for commentary.
Some of it needs to be tabulated in big two-column tables.

So I used package `longtable` because

1. it spreads tables nicely on several pages,
2. it accommodates footnotes (table does not).

Problem: 
`\marginpar` command doesn't work with `longtable`, so the margin notes won't appear when called, but show up the next time you use `\marginpar` in plain text thus shifting the whole marginal notes.
How can I get marginal notes while in a table environment?

Secondary problem: it would be very nice to use footnotes in marginal notes (that would be counted as a normal footnote, and appear at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 5):

Ha!
I found the solution: it's called `\marginnotes` an extention on `\marginpar`.
It works with `longtable` and accomodates footnotes inside margin notes.